# National Spanish soccer lotteries - La Quiniela and El Quinigol datasets

Tags: data-request, sports, data-format, europe

Looking for any of those National Spanish soccer lotteries in format similar to :

```
week, game 1, game 2 .... Chances: Home (game 1), Draw (game 1), Away (game 1)    ...

1       X       2                     20%             35%            45%
2       1       X                     60%             20%            20%
```

PS. Info about lotteries here - https://www.quinielista.es/index.asp?fuseaction=home